# Adding Image Hyperlinks from Forms to Excel via Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I have a MS Form where we have to upload photos for reporting purposes. I am wanting this to go into an excel doc to be able to run reports off the other fields. I am stuck on getting the image links into excel and have them be hyperlinks. I figure out how to get the links but they show up just as regular text and not as hyperlinks.

Is this even possible?

Pictures and steps:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Compose output:
[
"https://$$$$$$$$$$/EXwZSe6A6VFGsC2Z4DpBF5sBKPpYkrWAFXU0ggixkXBKdQ",
"https://$$$$$$$$$$/EVTSn5vMKodEi6NesjapFakBhfjoTvd_wOhLbxxhWAkPwQ",
"https://$$$$$$$$$$/EeO9TryHFEpOj6cEk_wdas8B-nTcfICYsieNHRCFRUlTLg"
]

I would like for these links to be at least
Link1
Link2
Link3

Without all the [] "" stuff
Thanks

Comment: Please show your attempt. A couple of screenshots and the mechanism you’re using will help us help you.  If you're using the `Add row to table` operation, you'll likely need to employ a different method, OR, you can augment your flow with additional functionality if need be.

Comment: @Skin sorry about that I added them.

Comment: Ok, so just to be clear, you want to extract each url and add that to your spreadsheet one by one but you want the url in the cell to be a link that someone can click on, is that right?

Comment: No I want them all in 1 cell but to be able to click on each of them. If they have to copy and paste so be it and I just remove the extra stuff that's fine too.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that’s not possible. The best way to tell is to try and make it work in excel directly first I could t make it work. It’s one url per cell as far as I can work out. Happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: What about doing a remove and replace. Remove the [] and " " replace with spaces?

Comment: But so you want them to be clickable or just stored separated by space? I assumed it was the former. If you just want them stored and not clickable then that’s quite straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I haven't been able to find a way to have more than one clickable hyperlink in a cell within Excel.

However, if you just want to string all of the URL's together, you can do so via the `join()` expression.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#join

I created a basic flow that demonstrates the usage.  You can see the results below.  For the `Initialize variable` step, this is the expression I used ...

```
join(outputs('Compose'), ' ')
```

It separates each value by a space.

#### Result

[image: Result]